# I get this error in Joomla 3.2, with a white screen

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

When I try to upload a new template in Joomla 3.2 (in my computer with apache, XAMPP), I get a white screen, without any error. I check the log file error, and I found these errors. Wish some of you can solve it. I don't understant what it means.

Thank you.

```
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:14.346499 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:14.530510 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:15.234550 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:15.456563 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:15.456563 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Nov 26 2013 16:07:35
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:15.456563 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:15.461563 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4328:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5132
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:17.442676 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5132:tid 268] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:18.459734 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5132:tid 268] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 06 01:54:18.613743 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5132:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Are you trying to run with ssl? ALso from the eror messages maybe you want to restart apache.

Comment: Please format that wall of text a little better. Have you turned on developer error mode?

Answer (score 0):

This error might be appearing probably because Apache checks the domain name for the certificate and the key. This is a warning message but you can disable SSL in the httpd.conf file

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Comment out the line using `#` like shown above.